# Boost score to different fields in Lucene

Tags: search, lucene

I have 2 fields "title" and "body" in my document. I want to give more weightage to title field. In latest Lucene 8.6* setboost is not available for field object. I want to know the best way to do this. I read PerFieldSimilarityWrapper can be used but I didn't get how to use it and in documentation warning is present "WARNING: This API is experimental and might change in incompatible ways in the next release." So is it safe to use in product which will be supported for long time.

Answer (score 0):

I too wish I understood more about why Lucene sometimes marks portions of their API as "experimental".  But one thing I can tell you, which should be fairly reassuring, is that there are large portions of the API marked this way and many haven't changed much in years and years.

So for example the class you are interested in `PerFieldSimilarityWrapper`  was marked as experimental at least as far back as Lucene 4.8.  See the tag on the 4.8 version in [github](https://github.com/apache/lucene/blob/releases/lucene-solr/4.8.0/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/PerFieldSimilarityWrapper.java#L33).

So, I don't think I'd be too concerned.  Especially because if the Lucene team ever decides to change the API they won't immediately remove it.  They typically mark the old API as depreciated (but still callable) for at least on major version.

Comment: do you know how to use PerFieldSimilarityWrapper? I didnt find much on this even in Lucene documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It was really hard to find a good 2020+ answer on this one. The easiest way I found is by including a boost Map with `MultiFieldQueryParser`, and creating a `Query` as follows:

```
Query query = new MultiFieldQueryParser(fields, analyzer, Map.of("title", 2f, "body", 1f))
     .parse(yourQueryString);
```

The boost values are arbitrary, this will weight "title" higher though.